# Can I remove a Delta Recruit Character without consequences?

Tags: star-trek-online

Characters created in STO between April 2 and May 21, 2015 became [Delta Recruits](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Delta_Recruitment), which had some benefits over "regular" characters.

Delta Recruit characters are marked by a small Delta sign next to the rank insignia:

[image]

Creating a Delta Recruit also added benefits for other characters of the player, which were created before or after that period.

These benefits could be collected by visiting a temporal agent in the factions headquarter, for example for federation characters this is Philip Crey at Earth Space Dock:

[image]

I don't really play my Delta Recruit character anymore, it just doesn't fit my play style, so I'm wondering what happens if I delete the character to make space for new ones. Will I still be able to get the benefits from the Delta Recruit program with new characters?

Comment: If you haven't already deleted it, Season 11.5 released 2016/04/12. It revamps the skill system, which gives everybody a chance to respec. You can't change class, but you may be able to rebuild to something more to your liking.